# google image search shell api

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looking for something like API for google-image search using in bash shell.

I want to gel list of links and resolution-info for some query string.

The ideal will be `curl`ing or `wget`ing any page and than parsing results.

But I cannot find any parseble page variant.

I'm trying `$> curl "http://images.google.com/images?q=apple"` and get nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably go read Google's Terms of Service first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are APIs for Google's searches; http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch although I don't know how you would meed the referrer/branding licensing requirements.

Comment: > _The Google Search APIs let you put Google Search in your web pages with JavaScript_. Not a single word about shell\bash etc. Unusable

Comment: Yes.. but its just text, curl it & parse out what you want; http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google Images does not like curl (403 error code).
To avoid the 403 error, you need to fake the user agent, like this:

`wget -qO- "http://images.google.com/images?q=apple" -U "Firefox on Ubuntu Gutsy: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080418 Ubuntu/7.10 (gutsy) Firefox/2.0.0.14"`

Still, I guess this is not enough since you get a load of javascript code, that needs to be executed somehow.

My 2 cents.